# Can I play Pocket Edition on my computer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm looking for a Minecraft game to use and I wondered if MC:PE would work on my computer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. Minecraft Pocket Edition is for devices. Without an emulator, you cannot play it on a computer.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. sounds like an answer.

Comment: Not sure why this is being considered off topic, but I dont see any reason to close this. VTLO

Answer (score 0):

Pocket Edition won't work with any desktop operating system, only on iOS/Android/ Amazon Fire TV/Windows Phone, but Windows 10's Minecraft 'Windows 10 Edition' seems to share a lot of similarities with the mobile version.

Comment: Windows 10 Edition is basically MCPE ported onto computers.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. It's so similar, you can play together! One on iPhone and one on windows ten! It isn't "basically" it ***IS***